# Kubevela Installation problem/ helm is not showing releases

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm v3.6.1 on Kubernetes v1.21.1

`helm list` shows no releases.

```
NAME    NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED STATUS  CHART   APP VERSION
```

Getting Error in kubevela installation

```
helm install --create-namespace -n vela-system kubevela kubevela/vela-core
```

`Error: failed to download "kubevela/vela-core" (hint: running` helm repo update `may help)`

```
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --version v1.2.0 --create-namespace --set installCRDs=true
```

`Error: cannot re-use a name that is still in use`

Anyone pls help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First try to run the command

```
helm repo update
```

and after that try running the command to install the `cert manager`.

```
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --version v1.2.0 --create-namespace --set installCRDs=true
```

For this error

```
Error: cannot re-use a name that is still in use
```

it might be possible **cert-manager** is already running inside the cluster.

Try listing using

```
helm ls -n <Namespace to check>
```

**Note** :

it also possible if you had previously installed the `cert-manager` with helm version **v2** and you are trying to list the all template with helm **v3** it won't show anything.

Make sure helm version is proper.